# Arduino - Calculating the time for which a Pushbutton is pressed and held without being released

Tags: arduino-uno, button, time

I'm working on a project that requires calculating the time for which a pushbutton is kept pressed without being released. Is there a code snippet that i can use for this particular need ?

Comment: Constrain your question.  Are you talking Minutes? Seconds?  Milliseconds?  If milliseconds, how do you plan on contending with switch bounce?

Comment: Milliseconds only. I haven't figured out the solution for the bounce problem yet.

Comment: Was not asking how you were going to solve it.  Wanted to know how you were going to interpret it. Guessing, I would say you want to start counting in millisecond increments on first contact.  Then I am going to assume you want to stop counting at last contact.  But the tricky bit: You will not know about last contact until after (depending on the quality of your switch) 10s of milliseconds goes by with out additional contacts.  So, what ever solution you choose, you will need to consider these issues and guess at the timing, try them then adjust them until you get the desired results.

Comment: Yeah that is exactly how I'am interpreting this question. Okay let me try and get back here. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called "Debounce", which you can find here: [playground.arduino.cc](https://playground.arduino.cc/uploads/Code/Debounce.zip). Based on that library, here is a simple sketch that displays the amount of time a button is pressed.

```
// Connect one end of a N.O. push button switch to GND and the other
// end to pin 4 of the Arduino.
// NOTE: If the button is held down for less than the debounce delay
//       time, the elapsed time will display the debounce delay time.
#include <Debounce.h>
const byte SWITCH = 4;
unsigned long startTime = 0;
unsigned long endTime = 0;
unsigned long elapsedTime = 0;
const byte debounceDelayTime = 50;

Debounce debouncer = Debounce(debounceDelayTime, SWITCH);

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(SWITCH, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop(){
  if(debouncer.update()){
    if(debouncer.read() == 0){
      startTime = millis();
      Serial.println("Button Pressed");
    }
    else if(debouncer.read() == 1){
      endTime = millis();
      Serial.println("Button Released");
      elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
      Serial.print("Button Held Down For ");
      Serial.print(elapsedTime);
      Serial.println(" ms.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The `millis()` overflow shouldn't be an issue, since the substraction `endTime - startTime` will also overflow, since `elapsedTime` is also an `unsigned long`.

Comment: Hi VE7JRO, I get this error, is there something wrong with importing the library ? :Arduino: 1.8.5 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

C:\Users\user\Desktop\buttonpresstrial3\buttonpresstrial3.ino:1:22: fatal error: debounce.h: No such file or directory

 #include <debounce.h>

                      ^

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Comment: Sorry @VishwaV, you can find it here: https://playground.arduino.cc/uploads/Code/Debounce.zip. I'll update my answer. I'm using version 1.0.6.2 of the IDE, and I'm guessing the newer versions use the updated Bounce2 libraries.

Comment: Hi @VE7JRO, Even after importing it to my libraries folder in arduino, I'm getting this error : D:\arduino-1.8.5\libraries\Debounce\Debounce.cpp:2:22: fatal error: WProgram.h: No such file or directory .  What should i do ?

Comment: On line 2 of Debounce.cpp, remove this: #include "WProgram.h" and replace it with this: #include "Arduino.h".

Comment: I replaced it with the help of notepad and the error still persists @VE7JRO

Comment: Try adding a couple of blank lines to the top of Debounce.cpp. The error was on line 22 (Debounce.cpp:2:22) the first time. Adding blank lines should change the line number of the error. We need to verify you are editing the right file.

Comment: Hi @VE7JRO i added a couple of blank lines to the top of debounce.cpp file and the error still stays on line 22. Am i editing the wrong file then ?

Comment: Yes, you are editing the wrong file.

Comment: Oops , okay wait this is what I did, I saw the Debounce.cpp file. Converted it into wordpad format and changed the line as you said. After doing this, i saved it back in the word format. Should i change it back to cpp format or anything like that ?

Comment: And the error has an additional line now :
Multiple libraries were found for "Debounce.h"
 Used: C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Debounce
 Not used: D:\arduino-1.8.5\libraries\Debounce

Comment: It looks like the IDE can't decide whether to use the library on C drive or D drive. I would remove one of the duplicate libraries. File name should be: Debounce.cpp. I'm not familiar with wordpad. Do you have a simple text editor?

Comment: Hii @VE7JRO , you were right i removed one of those duplicate libraries and got it right. Your code is working absolutely fine now, Thanks.